# How to store value from grep output in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on one bash script, in which I have to use the regular expression to match string and then store the output in a variable to reuse it.

here is my script,

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="MET-3-get-code-from-string"
por="$($NAME | grep -P -o -e '(?<=MET-).*?(\d+)')"    #this should store 3 in variable por

echo $por
```

I tried this many ways, but I am getting error :
**./check.sh: MET-3-get-issue-id-from-branch-name: not found**

if I run individual grep command then yes, it is working properly. But I am not able to store output.

I also tried :

```
por=$($NAME | grep -P -o -e '(?<=MET-).*?(\d+)')
por=$NAME | grep -P -o -e '(?<=MET-).*?(\d+)'
```

and many other similar references.

but it's not working. can anyone please help me on this. I have not much experience in bash.

thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
por="$($NAME | grep -P -o -e '(?<=MET-).*?(\d+)')"
```

to

```
por="$(echo "$NAME" | grep -P -o -e '(?<=MET-).*?(\d+)')"
```

Also, you are missing a closing double quote (maybe just a typo, should be `NAME="MET-3-get-code-from-string"`)